# Создание приложения с получением текущей погоды (много запросов)

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго дня! Хочу написать живые обои, которые отображают погоду в реальном времени. Уже определился с источником данных - openweathermap.org. Но возник следующий вопрос: как правильно получать эти данные в приложении? На openweathermap стоит ограничение в 60 запросов в минуту. Соответсвенно если обращаться из приложения напрямую на openweathermap под одной учетной записью, то при большом количестве загрузок моего приложения, это ограничение очень быстро будет достигнуто. Покупать платные подписки? Или же каким либо образом написать свой сервер на который будет загружаться все данные одним запросом, а приложение будет обращаться уже к моему серверу? Или есть другие пути решения?

Comment: Делай свой сервер, и пусть клиенты обращаются к нему, так думаю лучше будет.

Comment: Сделайте свой кэширующий прокси-сервер. Пусть он кэширует запросы клиентов, скажем, на 5 минут.

Comment: Вероятно, один запрос даёт погоду в определённом месте и времени. Нужен тогда такой сервер, чтобы хранил данные, которые нужны пользователям, а устаревшие быстро удалял.

Answer (score 3):

Свой проксирующий сервер. На нем настроить планировщик на циклическое обновление данных по квадратам

> Cities within a rectangle zone
>   Description:
>
> JSON returns the data from cities within the defined rectangle
>   specified by the geographic coordinates.
>
> Parameters:
>
> bbox bounding box [lon-left,lat-bottom,lon-right,lat-top]
>
> callback javascript functionName
>
> cluster use server clustering of points. Possible values ​​are [yes,
>   no]
>
> lang language [ru, en ... ]
>
> Examples of API calls:
>
> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/box/city?bbox=12,32,15,37,10&cluster=yes

А еще лучше так

1) поступает запрос от пользавателя

2) Если локальных данных по городу нет, либо они сильно устарели(>30м например) - загружаешь квадрат(круг) 200х200 км вокруг точки запроса и кешируешь все города