# Написание прокси-сервера для чайника

Tags: сервер, proxy, кэширование, прокси

В прошлом вопросе ([Вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535336/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)) я выяснил , что для запроса погоды мне нужен прокси сервер, который будет кэшировать данные с погодного сервера. Писать сервер придется мне самому, но до этого ни с чем подобным не сталкивался (серверной частью). Писать решил на python 3. Можете ли ткнуть в литературу или дать ссылки как можно реализовать такой кэширующий сервер, и правильно ли я вообще выбрал python?

Comment: [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

«По-науке» эта конструкция называется «Обратный прокси» (reverse proxy).
У вас есть некоторый backend-сервер, который генерирует какие-то полезные данные, и есть  frontend-сервер, который кеширует на себе редкоизменяемые данные. Такая схема чаще используется, для кеширования локальных ресурсов какого-нибудь сайта, чтобы не гонять данные лишний раз, через основной backend-сервер.

В вашем случае backend-сервером будет погодный сервер.

Если, логику формирования запросов клиенты возьмут на себя, то проще будет использовать некий уже готовый и отлаженный web-сервер. В принципе, тут подойдет любой (`nginx`, `lighttpd`, `apache`, Ваш собственный). 
Чаще всего для таких целей используют **nginx**. Он весьма шустр и достаточно прост в настройке.

Вот, например, настройки для `nginx`:

- http://reviewsignal.com/blog/2013/08/29/reverse-proxy-and-cache-server-with-nginx/

  - http://ashep.org/2011/nginx-obratnyj-proksi-server/#.V6ECut_XfmE

Официальная документация:

- https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

В итоге у вас получится что-то вроде:

```
events {
    worker_connections  8096;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {

    proxy_cache_path /tmp/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=cache:60m max_size=1G;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  your-proxy-server-name.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass              http://any-weather-server.com;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            proxy_cache             STATIC;
            proxy_cache_valid       200  1d;
            proxy_cache_use_stale   error timeout invalid_header updating \
                                    http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        }
    }
}
```

Тут надо будет внимательно отнестись к заголовкам, которые ожидает сервер погоды от вас. Вероятно, вам придется немножко поколдовать с

- `proxy_ignore_headers`
- `proxy_hide_headers`
- `proxy_set_headers`

Подобную проблему обсуждают тут:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230812/nginx-as-cache-proxy-not-caching-anything

Заголовки, вам придется настраивать в любом случае, в том числе и если frontend-сервер будете писать сами.

---

Если писать самому, я думаю, было бы проще найти некоторое готовое решение, и его переиспользовать.
Например, достаточно просто это сделать с помощью `tornado`.
А в качестве кеша использовать наример `memcached` или `redis`.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524545/how-to-write-a-web-proxy-in-python